# C# driver Cassandra possibly leaking memory. How can avoid running out of memory?

Tags: c#, database, memory-management, cassandra, memory-leaks

I am working with C# using the [official Cassandra Driver](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver). I have 5 tables and each table has around 300 columns. My requests are each for tens of thousands of rows. In total the data I consume is around 20 to 30 MB per each request. I am ok with each request taking 4 or 5 times memory to process a request. But after a request ends, I would expect the memory to go down on the next GC cycle. But it does not. However long I wait (Or even try to do it manually). With each request, the memory consumption of my app strictly increases. I have even removed all the code related to processing the data or returning it. Or even mapping the rows. Just querying cassandra takes memory that will never be GCed unless the app stops and the OS clears it. Here is the code I tested with:

```
byte[]? pagingState = null;
do
{
    cql = $"SELECT {string.Join(',', validColumnsWithMetadata)} FROM {table} WHERE "
        .FilterCurrentOperation(operationId, jobId)
        .And()
        .FilterTimestampRange(start, end)
        .EndQuery();
    var statement = new SimpleStatement(cql);
    statement.SetAutoPage(false).SetPageSize(pageSize);
    if (pagingState is not null)
    {
        statement.SetPagingState(pagingState);
    }

    using RowSet? response = await session.ExecuteAsync(statement)
        .WaitAsync(cancellationToken); // disposing RowSet [is not even recommened](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/csharp/3.0/html/M_Cassandra_RowSet_Dispose.htm), I did it just in case
    pagingState = response.PagingState;
    if (response is null)
    {
        break;
    }

    foreach (var row in response)
    {
        // Literally do nothing
    }
}
while (pagingState is not null);
```

I have tried to simiplify the problem removing all the code that could cause issues and I am left with literally querying the database and doing nothing with the data and still the memory issue persists. This issue is reproducable by creating a test table with >300 columns and 50K rows. Just add random timestamp, uuid, or string values in the columns

Comment: "I would expect the memory to go down on the next GC cycle. But it does not." How do you know this? The GC doesn't necessarily run as soon as the memory is no longer being used, only in [very specific circumstances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#conditions-for-a-garbage-collection). Do you actually run out of usable memory?

Comment: Yes, I actually run out of memory. I keep increasing the memory allocation for my pod due to this issue. I had 214 out of memory exceptions in the past 2 days.

Comment: your best bet is to try to get some memory dumps and see what is holding that memory

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JoãoReis. I tried using Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools to take memory snapshots at multiple instances while my app was running but the most I could see was 80 MB usage of memory while the actual memory consumption was around 500 MB. My suspicion is the unmanaged memory usage by the cassandra driver is not being deallocated properly. Or perhaps I am not disposing objects properly? I am not sure